# how to pass data in webservice using JSON object

Tags: android

if u have any kind of link or example about this please send me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in HTTP API. Start here: http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html

Answer (score 1):

Kindly check the following url for reference

http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/04/30/android-accessing-restfull-web-services-using-json/